# Copying specific struct members to another structure

Tags: c, struct, copy

so I have a file from which I have to load a number of tracks, find tracks longer than 3:30 and find the average bpm of those tracks.

Here's the code I have.

Main file:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include "functions.h"
int main(void)
{
   Playlist *all, *long_tracks;
   float avg_bpm;
   all = load_tracks("tracks.txt");
   long_tracks = get_tracks_longer_than(3,30,all);
   print_playlist(long_tracks);
   avg_bpm = get_avg_bpm(long_tracks);

   printf("Average BPM of the playlist is: %.2f\n", avg_bpm);

   return 0;
}
```

Header:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H 

typedef struct track {
char track[250];
float bpm;
int mm, ss;
} Track;

typedef struct playlist {
int count;
Track **tracks;
} Playlist;


void print_playlist(Playlist *list);
Playlist* load_tracks(char *filename);
Playlist* get_tracks_longer_than(int mm, int ss, Playlist* all);
float get_avg_bpm(Playlist *list);

#endif
```

Functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "functions.h"


void print_playlist(Playlist *list) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < list->count; i++) {
    printf("%s (%d:%d) [%f]\n", list->tracks[i]->track, list->tracks[i]->mm, list->tracks[i]->ss, list->tracks[i]->bpm);
  }
}

Playlist* load_tracks(char *filename) {
  int n,i;
  Playlist *list = (Playlist*) malloc(sizeof(Playlist));
  Track *tracks;

  FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
  fscanf(f, "%d", &n);
  printf("Tracks: %d\n", n);

  tracks = (Track*) malloc(n*sizeof(Track));
  list->tracks = (Track**) malloc(n*sizeof(Track*));

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fscanf(f, "%d:%d", &tracks[i].mm, &tracks[i].ss);
    fscanf(f, "%f", &tracks[i].bpm);
    fgetc(f);
    fgets(tracks[i].track, 250, f);
    tracks[i].track[strlen(tracks[i].track)-1] = '\0'; 
    list->tracks[i] = &tracks[i];
  }


  list->count = n;
  return list;
}

Playlist* get_tracks_longer_than(int mm, int ss, Playlist* all) {
    Playlist *longSongs = (Playlist*) malloc(sizeof(Playlist));

    Track *tracks;
    tracks = (Track*) malloc(all->count*sizeof(Track));
    longSongs->tracks = (Track**) malloc(all->count*sizeof(Track*));

    int i, n = 0;

    for(i=0;i<all->count;i++)
    {

        if(all->tracks[i]->mm>mm)
        {
            n++;
            memcpy ( &longSongs, &all, sizeof(all) ); //I also tried longSongs[i]=all[i];
        }
        else if(all->tracks[i]->mm==mm)
        {
            if(all->tracks[i]->ss>ss)
            {
            n++;
            memcpy ( &longSongs, &all, sizeof(all) );
            }
        }
    }

    longSongs->count=n;
    return longSongs;
}

float get_avg_bpm(Playlist *list) {
    float avg_bpm=0;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<list->count;i++)
    {
        avg_bpm+=list->tracks[i]->bpm;
    }

    return avg_bpm/=list->count;

}
```

Problem is in my get_tracks_longer_than function, in which I don't really know how to copy the struct member I want from source structure to the destination structure, I only managed to copy all members from one structure to the other.
My n counter counts number of tracks correctly, and my function which calculates bpm seems to work, but I don't know how to get the exact data I want.
I tried using memcpy function, tried assigning it like this: `longSongs[i]=all[i]`, and I tried manually assigning values, e.g:

```
longSongs->tracks[i]->mm = all->tracks[i]->mm;
longSongs->tracks[i]->ss = all->tracks[i]->ss;
longSongs->tracks[i]->bpm = all->tracks[i]->bpm;
```

but nothing works, it always copies all members of the source structure, ignoring my if statements.

Comment: Why don't you want to copy the whole `Track` structure?

Comment: BTW, using two `if()` statements to compare the times is not best. Just combine the minutes and seconds: `total_secs = mm*60+ss;`

Comment: I do want to copy the whole track structure (track name, mm, ss, bpm). I don't want to copy the whole playlist structure which contains all songs in the file to my structure, I only want to copy those songs from the playlist which contains all songs whose duration exceeds 3:30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to copy the members, just copy the pointers.

```
longSongs->tracks[n] = all->tracks[i];
```

Note that the index into `longSongs->tracks` is `n`, not `i`. Otherwise, you'll leave gaps in the `longSongs->tracks` array for all the songs that didn't get selected.

```
Playlist* get_tracks_longer_than(int mm, int ss, Playlist* all) {

    int min_secs = mm*60 + ss;

    Playlist *longSongs = malloc(sizeof(Playlist));
    longSongs->tracks = malloc(all->count*sizeof(Track*));

    int i, n = 0;

    for(i=0;i<all->count;i++)
    {
        if(all->tracks[i]->mm*60 + all->tracks[i]->ss > min_secs)
        {
            longSongs->tracks[n++] = all->tracks[i];
        }
    }

    longSongs->count=n;
    return longSongs;
}
```

Other changes: I removed the unused `tracks` variable, and I simplified comparing the running times by combining minutes and seconds into just total seconds.

Comment: Thank you so much!